# Canvas App makes successful REST API call, but response object is empty

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-formula, power-platform, power-apps-custom-connector

My Canvas App makes a successful REST API call, and in the Monitor log I can see that the response contains the data I'm expecting. However, the variable that the app assigns the response to (via the UpdateContext command) contains no data. What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out the issue. The response object defined in my imported Postman collection had the field names listed as lower case, but the actual response was upper case. My Canvas App wasn't able to resolve the data because the field names are case sensitive. I fixed this by going to the edit page for my Custom Connector, enabling the Swagger Editor, and updating the field names.